# should i need to create thread for my app?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

Everything works fine .My app does not stream any music from internet.Its just playing 50 files using raw folder..is necessary to create thread for my app?while playing music (using main thread ) affects incoming calls  and notifications?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream over internet actually you have to do it in another thread rather than `UIThread(Main Thread)` since starting from `API Level 11` and above making networking operations on UI thread is blocked and if you attempt to make it on `UIThread(MainThread)` you will get an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Service` to do some operations

Comment: if you want to play music in backgroud you should create a servie,if not you can do it in Activity on UIThread and loading resources in another thread.